# Why layout is disturbing even using width in dp Android

Tags: android

I have created a demo application in Android using `Nexus 9 2048 X 1536` 
I have added an EditText and assign width as 1000dp it is working fine in Nexus 9 Emulator. But When I change the Emulator as `Nexus 5X 1080 X 1920` to test the `dp` purpose, Then the EditText goes out of the layout and shown about half of it.

Why it is happening even I assign the width in dp. It should adjust the width by screen-resolution.

Answer (score 3):

> It should adjust the width by screen-resolution.

No, it does not. `dp` will adjust the width by screen **density**, not screen **resolution**. You asked for it to be 1000dp wide, and so it will be 1000dp wide, regardless of screen resolution or screen size.

Comment: So how we can create responsive design in Android? if we need to assign width as fixed dp?

Comment: @NoorRehman: By definition, "width as fixed dp" is *not* a "responsive design". You are welcome to create different versions of your layout resource for different scenarios, such as different screen widths. For example, `res/layout/main.xml` would be used normally, but `res/layout-w800dp/main.xml` would be used for screens whose current width is 800dp or larger.

Comment: you can also use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to set your EditText size to max.

Comment: So just last what is best practice to make response? wrap_content and match_parent?

Comment: @NoorRehman: "Best practices" depend a lot upon the situation. Sometimes, you can get away with having a single flexible layout, using things like `wrap_content` and `match_parent`. Sometimes, you need to provide multiple layouts to achieve your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few alternatives:

1) The right and recommended one is to make different layouts for different screens. For this alternative see [Supporting multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

2) Another alternative I used to use before ConstraintLayout was to make everything proportional. When the app starts I take the meassurement of the Display and layout everything based on that. This is done mostly programatically not using the xml layout file.

3) Use the new ConstraintLayout from the support library. Using this layout you can constraint your widgest relative to each other and or to guidelines you can add to your layout to delimit sections of it. Your widgets that need to adapt will mostly have a width of 0dp or wrap_content and the constraints will take care of resizig them accordingly.

[Using ConstraintLayout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex)